# How to disable auto sort data of Realtime Database of Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I just realized that when I add some data into Realtime Database of Firebase and it's will be sorted by letter from a -> z. And in my case, I don't want that feature, so have any ways to disable that features ?

I don't know how to disable it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the way the Realtime Database (RTDB) nodes are sorted by default.

If you want, when you fetch data from the RTDB, to get the data in a different  order you'll need to use one of the [order-by methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data?hl=en&authuser=0#sort_data) (which may request the addition of sub-nodes dedicated to sorting).

*(You don't give enough details in your question to give a more detailed answer)*

Comment: I mean, when I add data to a child of RTDB, I expect it will be added to the start index. I just have an idea, but I don't know if it will work or not, which is that I will make a child and the value of this child will be a date time instead of ID is the value of the child. And RTDB can be sorted by date time ?

Comment: If you use a Timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) as you nodes key yes the RTDB will sort them by date time. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue#TIMESTAMP(). You could also add a child node with a Timestamp value to each node and use the `orderByChild()` method.

Comment: I got it, let me try. Thank you for your answers <3

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
firebase.database().ref('yourNode').push({
    // your data
});
```

Make use of:

```
firebase.database().ref('yourNode').child('customKey').set({
    // your data
});
```